# Handle null return values in Promise in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am quite new to typescript and have following issue.
I have following code where I can't reach `console.log('uid....' + uid);` when the `uid` is null

```
    deleteUser(email: string): Promise<User> {
            let uid: string;
            let p = new Promise<User>((resolve) => {
                this.loginService.getUserIdByEmail(email).then((getUserResponse) => {


**********************************
    ******** do not reach here when getUserResponse is NULL**********************
************************


                    uid = getUserResponse;
                    console.log('uid....' + uid);
                    if (uid !== null) {
                        let actions = [
                            this.siteUserTableService.deleteByRowKey(uid),
                            this.userSiteTableService.deleteById(uid),
                        ];
                        Promise.all(actions.map(this.reflect)).then(values => {
                            this.tableService.deleteById(uid).then((deleteResponse) => {
                                this.loginService.deleteUserByEmail(email);
                            });
                        });
                    }

                }).catch((err) => {
                    // Something wrong
                });
            });
            return p;
        };




getUserIdByEmail(email: string): Promise<string> {
        let searchParams = {
            query: 'select UID from accounts where profile.email = "' + email + '"'
        };

        let p = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        login.accounts.search(searchParams).then((response) => {
            if (response.errorCode === 0 && response.results.length > 0) {
                resolve(response.results[0].UID);
            } else {
                console.log('No login user...');
                reject('');
            }
        });
    });
    };
```

As I am not getting a return value from `getUserIdByEmail` function (return null) I cannot proceed with `deleteUser`  function.

So how can I proceed even with null return value.

Thanks

Comment: You are ignoring all kind of errors in `getUserIdByEmail`. You might want to take the `reject` argument in the `Promise` constructor, and actually __reject__ it when something goes wrong.

Comment: @BalázsÉdes I have changed the code (in the question as well) as per your suggestion. Still produce the same result.

Comment: This is not really a TypeScript specific question, it applies to any JavaScript code including TypeScript code. You should not rely on returning `null` to signal failure. You should use `reject` if inside a promise as noted by @BalázsÉdes. Otherwise throw an `Error`. Also, this line `reject(p = null);` looks highly suspicious. It basically assigns `null` to the promise that it is rejecting....